# How can I sanitize laravel Request inputs?

Tags: php, laravel, forms, request, sanitization

I have `MyRequest.php` class extending `App\Http\Requests\Request`. I want to `trim()` every input before validation because an e-mail with a space after it does not pass validation.

However `sanitize()` was removed from `src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just came across for the same problem.
I'd like to show you another way of doing it without `extends` but with `traits`. ( I will take the Example Classes from Tarek Adam ).

PHP [Traits](http://php.net/manual/de/language.oop5.traits.php) are like functions which will be injected into the used class. The one main difference is that a Trait doesn't need any dependency like a extends do. This means you can use a trait for more then just one class e.x. for Controllers, Requests and whatever you like.

Laravel provides some traits in the BaseController, we can do the same.

### How to do it with a trait

Create a trait as file in `\App\Traits\SanitizedRequest.php`. You can create it anywhere it doesn't matter really. You have to provide the correct namespace for sure.

```
namespace App\Trait;

trait SanitizedRequest{

    private $clean = false;

    public function all(){
        return $this->sanitize(parent::all());
    }


    protected function sanitize(Array $inputs){
        if($this->clean){ return $inputs; }

        foreach($inputs as $i => $item){
            $inputs[$i] = trim($item);
        }

        $this->replace($inputs);
        $this->clean = true;
        return $inputs;
    }
}
```

In your Request you can use the trait with `use SanitizedRequest` keyword.

```
namespace App\Http\Requests\Forms;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;
use App\Trait\SanitizedRequest; // Import the Trait 

class ContactRequest extends Request {
    use SanitizedRequest; // This line adds all the Trait functions to your current class

    public function authorize(){ return true; }
    public function rules(){ return []; }
}
```

Comment: The trait approach offers more flexibility.  I suggest reading both answers to really understand it.  They kinda go together.

Answer (score 9):

1. Create an abstract SanitizedRequest class that extends the usual Request class.
2. YourRequest class should extend your SanitizedRequest abstract class.
3. Your SanitizedRequest class overrides Request::all() as like so...

   ```
   namespace App\Http\Requests\Forms;
   use App\Http\Requests\Request;

   abstract class SanitizedRequest extends Request{

       private $clean = false;

       public function all(){
           return $this->sanitize(parent::all());
       }


       protected function sanitize(Array $inputs){
           if($this->clean){ return $inputs; }

           foreach($inputs as $i => $item){
               $inputs[$i] = trim($item);
           }

           $this->replace($inputs);
           $this->clean = true;
           return $inputs;
       }
   }
   ```

Then a normal CustomRequest, but extend SanitizedRequest instead of laravel's Request class

```
    class ContactRequest extends SanitizedRequest{
        public function authorize(){ return true; }
        public function rules(){ return []; }
    }
```

Comment: If anyone is having problems copy/pasting this answer, it's likely the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 9 (not sure about older versions) you can extend `\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest` middleware and do apply your logic there. So lets say you need to encode your input with `htmlemntities()` function, create a middleware

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

class TransformsRequest extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest
{
    /** @inheritDoc */
    protected function transform($key, $value)
    {
        return is_string($value) ? htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8") : $value;
    }
}
```

Dont forget to apply this middleware globally in `App\Http\Kernel.php`

```
protected $middleware = [
    // other middlewares...
    \App\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest::class,
];
```

This middleware will encode each value that comes from input for all requests.