# Is this proper sanitization and whitelisting in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, security, sanitization

Using Laravel 5.7

I want to eventually extract this out as my own whitelister/sanitizer for use in all my form processing.

As I understand, Laravel Eloquent uses PDO for prepared statements so I am covered there for input into database.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post code in the form of screenshots but as formatted text (code) instead.

Comment: I'm not too sure if using the same regex for all inputs makes sense. `salary` for example should be numeric only. Why don't you use built-in validation with predefined rules?

Comment: might be simpler with request()->only($whitelist) but I haven't run it.

Comment: Also, seems like a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34820042/how-can-i-sanitize-laravel-5-x-request-inputs

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._cities_with_diacritics and ofc there are countries _other_ than the US with funny letters in their names too.

Comment: honestly i think this is a case of having completely over complicating something, I started by wondering how I can get around the idea that the validation process only returns the values that you validate, so I wanted to include other fields, then I also randomly decided to sanitize while whitelisting... Just realized that laravel provides 'nullable' and 'regex' validation rules, as well as basically functioning itself as a whitelist -.- thanks everyone

Comment: Laravel already sanitizes, in a variety of ways. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any particular "right" way to filter your inbound parameters.  Though I do think [Request::only()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests#retrieving-input) is a little cleaner than what you've got.

I find myself doing this a lot though, and have a preferred method for this.

1. Presuming you're referring a Controller method here, I highly recommend you [inject](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests) the `Request` object rather than use the helper function.
2. This gives you the opportunity to inject your own [custom Request class](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#creating-form-requests) and set up some validation rules.
3. Make that custom Request class, and any others you may want this behavior from, inherit your own base-class that in turn extends the `Illuminate\Http\Request` one.  This gives you the opportunity to use its automatically firing `prepareForValidation()` or `authorize()` methods.
4. Plug this snippet into one of those: https://gist.github.com/kmuenkel/8b926c398c22d7641ef1e99bb8c2508a

The end result will be that any parameter not listed in your `$rules` array within the custom Request will be stripped out.